# Thermal issues: surface mounted on 1" x 1" FR4 board

Tags: pcb, surface-mount, thermal, heatsink, footprint

A number of parts are rated at certain thermal impedance with a note, something along the lines of

> surface mounted on 1" x 1" FR4 board

like in this datasheet for instance - [MOSFET Vishay Siliconix SiSS05DN in a PowerPAK package](https://www.tme.eu/Document/8ae9fea82a7cb44d4c881a980e95a2fe/siss05dn.pdf)

Does this mean that in order to achieve the stated thermal impedance (63 C/W in this case) an 1 by 1 inches (exposed? free of any other parts?) copper square needs to be centered around the part, or more likely only around the biggest pad of the part? Or something else?

Also, how far apart would one place 4 of such parts in order to achieve the 63 C/W?

Comment: My reading is that they tested on a board that size.

Comment: The datasheet says nothing about copper on/in the board.  It just says a 1"x1" FR4 board.  I wold assume this also means no other heat producing devices on the board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably doesn't need to be centered, but you'll get slightly better performance by centering, the temperature has a gradient that gets lower in temperature the farther you get away from the component.

> Also, how far apart would one place 4 of such parts in order to
> achieve the 63C/W ?

This is a hard question to answer, it would really depend on the air as that is going to be the main pathway for the heat to escape. It depends on if the air is moving or still and how much convection there is. It would be faster to build and test it than to simulate with an FEM. I would try for at least an inch apart. If you are really worried about the temperature I'd just put heatsinks on the PCB or device.

Answer (score 3):

Thermal conductivity of sheet copper [the copper pours] is higher than it's ability to dump the heat from a PCB into the ambient air<sup>1,2</sup>.  As a result, the shape of the copper pour doesn't matter to a certain degree.  A 30 x 30 mm copper area will heatsink approximately as well as a 15 x 60 mm copper area.  The shape isn't confined to a rectangle; it can be a more complex shape, as long as it has the right area.

<sup>1</sup> For packages that are designed to heatsink to PCB.
<sup>2</sup> Assuming natural convection.

Comment: Nothing in the question or in the datasheet (that I could find) says anything about copper (pours, traces, or otherwise) in the board.

Comment: @SteveSh  Do you suspect that the test board consisted of just a a 1" x 1" piece of fiberglass (FR4), no planes, no copper pours, and the only copper on the board was the footprint (and maybe some minimal connection)?  FR4 by itself is a poor conductor of heat.

Comment: Minus any additional details in the datasheet - yep!  Because otherwise we get in all kinds a speculation about layer count, stackup, whether or not thermal vias were used, etc.